# Using '\\s' vs ' ' in regular expressions, is '\\s' looking for space and backslash simultaneously?

Tags: r

Say I use the string below:

```
x <- "County                           January 2016 February 2016         March 2016         April 2016       May 2016           June 2016         July 2016      August 2016 September 2016 October 2016             November 2016 December 2016\r"
```

What I gather from running the two commands below is that '\s' will seek out a ' ' (space) as well as a '\' backslash.

```
strsplit(x, "(?<=2016) +", perl=T)
[[1]]
 [1] "County                           January 2016"
 [2] "February 2016"                                
 [3] "March 2016"                                   
 [4] "April 2016"                                   
 [5] "May 2016"                                     
 [6] "June 2016"                                    
 [7] "July 2016"                                    
 [8] "August 2016"                                  
 [9] "September 2016"                               
[10] "October 2016"                                 
[11] "November 2016"                                
[12] "December 2016\r"                              

strsplit(x, "(?<=2016)\\s+", perl=T)
[[1]]
 [1] "County                           January 2016"
 [2] "February 2016"                                
 [3] "March 2016"                                   
 [4] "April 2016"                                   
 [5] "May 2016"                                     
 [6] "June 2016"                                    
 [7] "July 2016"                                    
 [8] "August 2016"                                  
 [9] "September 2016"                               
[10] "October 2016"                                 
[11] "November 2016"                                
[12] "December 2016"
```

Since the second command also splits on '\' following the last 2016.  Am I understanding this correct? I appreciate the help thanks.

Comment: Actually `\\s` stands for any white space (tabs, space,...) `\r` is carriage return, which is used in some windows systems. It is recognised by `\\s`, where as `' '` just recognises spaces.

Comment: @drmariod thanks a lot, that explains a lot of things actually.  i.e. `\r` is introduced for white space and with `\\s` Regex recognizes that.